# how to place label on top left corner of input field in html/css

Tags: html, css

Please refer the image below for reference. I want a similar kind of form with label being placed on top of input field in top left corner.

Img:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

--- update ---

I tried and i was able to place label separately on top of the input field and was unable to merge it.

this is how it looks currently:

[image]

```
<div class="form-group mt10">
            <label for="inputName">Name <span class="reqField">*</span></label>
            <input required type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputCountry">Country</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCountry" placeholder="Country">
        </div>
```

Comment: Just a friendly reminder that you should provide your own attempt to solve this with specific questions about your own code. StackOverflow is about answering questions and helping you to achieve what you need, not a free service to provide you the full solution. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i did but i am able to place it on top  but was unable to merge it.. ok i'll edit the question and add what i have achieved till now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will help.

```css
body.app-body {
    background: #cecece;
}
.form-group {
    border: 2px solid;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.form-group>label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 20px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #fff;
}

.form-group>input {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<body class="app-body">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <form id="first_name">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hey bud,**

I think what you are looking for is something similar to this. I certainly hope this helps, champion!

```css
.custom_badge {
     width:80px;
     height:30px;
     position:absolute;
     margin-top: -15px;
     border-radius:12px;
     -webkit-border-radius:12px;
     background:#708090;
     color:white;
     text-align:center;
     vertical-align:bottom;
     font-size:14px;
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: 400;
     font-family: arial,sans-serif;
     margin-left: 10px;
     padding-top:3px;
}
 .custom_input {
     border: none !important;
     border:solid 1px #708090 !important;
     border-radius:12px !important;
     -webkit-border-radius:12px !important;
     width:350px !important;
     text-align: end !important;
     color:#54606C !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"> </head>

<body class="app-body">
    <h5 class="lead small mx-2 text-info text-uppercase my-4">Rounded label on input field | Demo Code</h5>
    <div class="form-group mx-2">
        <label class="align-middle custom_badge" for="inputName">Name <span class="reqField">*</span> </label>
        <input required type="text" class="form-control custom_input" id="inputName"> </div>
    <div class="form-group mx-2 my-4">
        <label class="align-middle custom_badge" for="inputCountry">Country </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control custom_input" id="inputCountry"> </div>
</body>
```